# CakePHP ROOT constant

Tags: php, configuration, cakephp

The CakePHP `ROOT` constant, where should it point to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ROOT should be set to the path of the directory that contains your `app` folder.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/35/Advanced-Installation)

Answer (score 2):

ROOT Constant is defined in webroot/index.php

and by default it gives the full path to the directory which holds `"app"`, WITHOUT a trailing DS

means `"D:\xampp\htdocs\cake2.2.1"` if my `cakePHP` set up resides in `Cake2.2.1` directory on `xampp`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/317/Cake-s-Global-Constants-And-Functions) it's

> the name of the directory parent to
>   the base index.php of CakePHP.